# creating simple binded Kendo ui forms

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I'm looking at building a web based application to manage a customer database etc for a client.

I write in **PHP** but was looking at *Kendo UI* to do all the grid/form legwork. However I can see how to create a simple form using *Kendo UI*. I mean how would you create a form and bind it to a datasource if it's not a grid?.

Any help or even an alternative to *Kendo* would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? Kendo UI is a collection of user-interface components for the web. Kendo UI does not dictate how you create an HTML form, it enhances it. Did you look at the [demos](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mvvm/index)?

Comment: Hi Brett, Ive been using Kendo Grids, Lists etc which use datasources. Which is fine but in some cases i just need a form on a page that uses the kendo ui. It just seems odd how they don't show you a simple form binded to a datasource like a grid/list etc. I want to be able to use the datasources currently setup with some simple forms.

Comment: The link to the demo I gave you in my previous comment shows exactly what you are asking about. Each item in the data source is a Kendo UI Observable object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MVVM to bind a kendo observable (datasource) to any custom html you create.
Create a view model for your data

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({name: "John Doe",});
```

and bind it to your HTML.

```
kendo.bind($("#view"), viewModel);
<div id="view"><input data-bind="value: name" /></div>
```

Now everytime you change the 'name' fielt in the viewmodel the HTML will update.

**Edit:**
Datasource is a kendo.observable. Let your model/datasouce have the fields firstname and secondname, then you need to bind the datasource to the form.

```
kendo.bind($("#view"), yourKendoDataSource);
```

Your form should look like this (note the data-bind attributes, they bind your model to the ui)

```
<form id="view">
  First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" data-bind="value: firstname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" data-bind="value: lastname">
</form>
```

Comment: how would i attach this to a datasource so it can interact with my already written php scripts that i use for grids.